How to :set keymap=language in init.lua?
I'm new to NeoVim and vim in general, and I'm trying to set it up. I'm going to use it to write text in my native language and in order to execute vim commands I constantly have to switch the language. I want to avoid this by leaving my native language for the insert mod, and executing commands in English.
I found two links with the same problem:
link 1
link 2
But they were all written for vimrc in the form
:set keymap=language
I use init.lua to configure my vim and I would really like to understand how I should adapt this.

See https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua-guide.html#lua-guide-options

Thanks for the tip, I've already read this document. Thanks to endless searching, I came to vim.opt.keymap="language", but the problem now is that the editor by default launches me into this custom language, and not English, but its tolerable little thing.
